# Outputting Page Title As Tooltip

Tags: menus

I'm trying to output the page title via `wp_nav_menu()` as a tooltip (.pop_up). The menu text has been replaced by an icon, and using CSS to hide it.

Any ideas how this could be adapted to output the string name where the text "MENU LINK" is shown? Is this actually possible?

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'  => 'Main Menu',
    'after' => '<div class="pop_up">MENU LINK</div>'
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way... instead of using `wp_nav_menu()`

```
$menu_name = 'main-menu';

if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-main-menu">';
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $id = $menu_item->ID;
        $menu_list .= '<li id="menu-item-' . $id . '"><a href="' . $url . '"></a><div class="pop_up">' . $title . '</div></li>';
    }

    $menu_list .= '</ul>';

}

echo ($menu_list);
```